# Validar dentro de un Do While

Tags: genexus, genexus15

estoy realizando un formulario el cual me selecciona preguntas aleatorias desde una BD, la cantidad de preguntas las determina el administrador, pero bueno.
Siempre al inicio del cuestionario (Web Panel - Event Start) se seleccionan preguntas aleatorias mediante esta manera.

```
Event Start
    &a = 1
    Do While
       &preguntaSeleccionada.Add(Random() * &CantidadPreguntas)
       &a = &a + 1
    EndDo
EndEvent
```

Al multiplicar el  "`Random() * &cantidad`"  esto me da números del 1 hasta la última pregunta que tengo, pero hay momentos (muy poco) que se repiten y la idea no es esa.

Quisiera saber si mientras ese `Do While` funciona, hay alguna manera de validar que cuando se haga un "`&coleccon.Add(&item)`" no ingrese si ya existe un dato igual.

Trabajo con Gx15u8 - Java Web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes preguntar si un ítem está en la colección usando la función `IndexOf`, que devuelve cero si el elemento no está y distinto de cero (la posición en la colección en base 1) si lo pudo encontrar.

Tu código entonces quedaría algo así:

```
Event Start
    &a = 1
    Do While // falta la condición...
        &next = Random() * &CantidadPreguntas
        if &preguntaSeleccionada.IndexOf(&next) = 0
            &preguntaSeleccionada.Add(&next)
            &a = &a + 1
        endif
    EndDo
EndEvent
```